# How to validate so that at least 1 field is required from a group, when the 2nd field has two required fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Apologies for the confusing question title. I understand how to use the required_from_group method to ensure that at least 1 field is filled in from a group. I do it like this:

Example HTML

```
<form>
  <select name="ProductID" id="ProductID" class="js-product">
    <option value="1">Bounty</option>
    <option value="2">Snickers</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="ProductName" id="ProductName" class="js-product" />
  <select name="Country" id="Country">
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Here is example JQuery Validate to ensure the user selects a `ProductID` from the select dropdown, or they type in the product name in the `ProductName` textfield. It does this because the class of `.js-product` is applied to those two inputs to define it as a group.

```
$('form').validate({
...
rules: {
        ProductID: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".js-product"]
         },
        ProductName: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".js-product"]
         }
});
```

The issue I have is that if the user types in a Product Name, he also needs to specify the Country for that product. So I actually need the user to:

1. Fill in either the ProductID by selecting a product from the list OR type in the product name
2. If the User types in a product name manually, then they MUST also choose a Country from the dropdown where that product originates from

How do I ensure that `ProductName` and `'Country'` are in a group that is only required when the `ProductID`  drop down is left NULL?

One possible idea I thought of was to make the `Country` dropdown required on a `blur` event taking place in the `ProductName` field.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `depends` property](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules) along with [the `:filled` selector](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/selectors/) to make the `Country` field required only when the `ProductName` field is filled out.  It does not interfere with your `require_from_group` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').validate({
        // ....
        rules: {
            ProductID: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".js-product"]
            },
            ProductName: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".js-product"]
            },
            Country: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        // sets this rule to 'true' only when the condition is met
                        return $("#ProductName").is(":filled");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        // only for DEMO - simulated submission
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('form submitted');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form>
    <select name="ProductID" id="ProductID" class="js-product">
        <option value="">select...</option>
        <option value="1">Bounty</option>
        <option value="2">Snickers</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="ProductName" id="ProductName" class="js-product" />
    <br/>
    <select name="Country" id="Country">
        <option value="">select...</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```